# Why does the GUI freeze even with QThreadPool?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to build a custom Python console widget that uses a simple QTextEdit. A line edit box receives input and runs it through a python interpreter in a thread.

Here is interpreter.py

```py
import sys
from io import StringIO, IncrementalNewlineDecoder
from code import InteractiveConsole
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from stream import NewLineIO

class PythonInterpreter(QObject, InteractiveConsole):
    output = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
        self.l = {}
        InteractiveConsole.__init__(self, self.l)
        self.out = NewLineIO()
        self.out.output.signal_str.connect(self.console)

    def write(self, string):
        self.output.emit(string)

    def runcode(self, codez):
        """
        Reimplementation to capture stdout and stderr
        """
        sys.stdout = self.out
        sys.stderr = self.out
        sys.excepthook = sys.__excepthook__
        result = InteractiveConsole.runcode(self, codez) # Where the magic happens
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
        sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
        #self.output.emit(self.out.getvalue()) # Send the output
        return result

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def console(self, string):
        #print(string, file=sys.__stdout__)
        self.output.emit(string)

class JavaScriptInterpreter(QObject):
    pass
```

This is main.py

```py
import sys
from traceback import TracebackException
from PyQt5 import QtCore, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QThreadPool
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog,
                             QAction)
from PyQt5.Qsci import QsciScintilla, QsciLexerPython, QsciAPIs
from interpreters import PythonInterpreter
from lexers import PythonLexer
from threads import Worker, WorkerSignals
from stream import NewLineIO

class MainWindow(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

        self.ui = uic.loadUi("main.ui")
        self.ui.showMaximized()

        # Code Editor
        self.font = QFont()
        self.font.setFamily('Courier New')
        self.font.setFixedPitch(True)
        self.font.setPointSize(10)
        self.ui.code_editor.setFont(self.font)
        self.lexer = PythonLexer(self.ui, self.font)
        self.lexer.lock()

        # Console
        self.interpreter = PythonInterpreter()
        self.ui.console_log.isReadOnly()
        self.ui.console_input.returnPressed.connect(self.send_console_input)
        self.interpreter.output.connect(self.send_console_log)

        # Threads
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()

    def send_console_input(self):
        command = self.ui.console_input.text()
        self.ui.console_input.clear()
        worker = Worker(self.interpreter.push, str(command))
        worker.signals.result.connect(print)
        worker.signals.finished.connect(self.thread_complete)
        #self.interpreter.push(str(command))

        self.threadpool.start(worker)
        print("Thread Count: ", 
              self.threadpool.activeThreadCount(),
              file=sys.__stdout__)

    def thread_complete(self):
        print("Thread Complete !")

    def send_console_log(self, command):
        print(command, file=sys.__stdout__)
        self.ui.console_log.append(command)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The everytime the signal from the instance of `PythonInterpreter` is emitted it calls `self.send_console_log` which receives the output from the command that was run on the interpreter.

However, if I run a large loop like `for i in range(10000):print(i)` as a command sent to the interpreter through `self.send_console_input`, it will do the print statement in `self.send_console_log` fine, but not the `.append()`. It will freeze till the loop is done and the whole thing will get appended to the `QTextEdit`.

How can solve this issue?

Comment: @ekhumoro what is missing ? I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure but if GUI is main part it has to start first before other threads. It might happen some or one of treads start before GUI. Check these out

Comment: The GUI starts first. The line `self.ui.showMaximized()` in main.py

Comment: Have you tried splitting the numbers if number is greater then certain amount

Comment: It's an interpreter so it should be capable of doing it from one thread. Also, what do you mean splitting the numbers?

Comment: Let's say you have 1000, to make this 500 - 500.

Comment: Add try- except on appending part and see what is error. That makes more helpful